# Time accuracy improved starting with iOS 8.2?

Tags: ios, synchronization, apple-watch, ntp

My app uses an NTP server to get a more precise time than the iOS system clock. However, a poster at http://watch.camp/2014/11/apple-watch-timekeeping-accuracy/ suggests that with iOS 8.2, the iOS system clock is much more accurate because it's used to keep the Apple Watch within 50ms of true time. Can I therefore not bother to use an NTP server if the iOS version is 8.2 or greater? Thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, according to my checks the time accuracy has been greatly improved in iOS 8.2.1, most probably because of the Apple Watch launch. Looks like Apple either upgraded their NTP servers or changed the way how iOS synchronises its clock.

EDIT: Most probably both ... According to a comment on that page you refer to something changed in the response coming from Apple servers